Is it possible to explain the fluorescence of olive oil under a green laser pointer using Maxwell's equations or non-linear versions of them?
Is it possible to explain the fluorescence of olive oil under a green laser pointer using Maxwell's equations or non-linear versions of them?

Intro__________
In the following Youtube short video it is shown what happens when you direct a green laser pointer on a colorless flask containing olive oil, showing inside a path of red light due fluorescence:

Explanations I found explains it through electron level jumps which use to be modeled through quantum mechanics.

Question___________
It is possible to model the fluorescence of the olive oil using Maxwell's equations? meaning here the traditional equations including the classic electromagnetic wave equation, or also non-linear versions of the wave equation and it's correspondent adjusted Maxwell's equations.

Motivation__________
As example, the Non-linear Schrödinger equation is an adjustment to the traditional Schrödinger equation in order to model accurately some phenomena of light traveling in fiber optics, and I wonder if there are ways to adjust the electromagnetic wave equation in order to represent phenomena where the wavelength of light changes (which cannot be done with the classic linear electromagnetic wave equation so far I know).
On this other question I think it should be possible to have a differential equation that show arbitrary frequency mixing, but I believe that any truncated Taylor's series representation of the non-linearity will lead only to harmonics solutions, so it wouldn't represent accurately every admissible scenario.

update 1 - optional reading________
After some comments I would like to pinpoint why I believe the question is interesting (at least for me): If I think of using a classical math function to model the jump of the electron while emitting the red light, this phenomena, that has happened on a finite interval of time, should be modeled with a function with finite duration in the time variable, meaning it should have an initial time and a finite extinction time. This will make the function compact-supported on the time variable, then by the Paley–Wiener theorem this function spectrum will be an Entire function, so, I would be expecting to have a widespread bandwidth, meaning for the example of fluorescence, maybe the presence of additional frequencies/colors, as expected by the Bandlimited versus timelimited Uncertainty principle given by Gabor's Limit. Being true that an entire function could in principle model a very narrow Gaussian shape, it's neverending non-zero values should make some kind of additional colors (I believe).
After reading the following papers by Vardia T. Haimo about Finite Time Differential Equations paper 1 paper 2, I understand now that first and second order ODEs must have a Non-Lipschitz term in order to able to admit solutions with a finite extinction time. Then, I expect that the dynamical model explainning the electron orbital jump would be having a Non-Lipschitz component, but so far I know current quantum models' differential equations don't have these kind of terms (correct me if I am mistaken please), so I am looking if there are any, or if it is even possible, to model these phenomena of finite time extension with classic electromagnetism.
In this line, having this finite time extension would mean necessarilly that the differential equation will be somehow dissipative, and after seeing this Youtube video where it is explained that no Lagrangian, neither Hamiltonian mechanics, are able to model accurately dissipative systems, I wonder now if mainstream physics maybe have ignored the possibility of having systems that could stop moving in finite time, somehow using instead least accurate models, as example, any time I see a Youtube video about the nature of time, it is explained that physics' laws cannot determine the direction of time, well, if you are using math that cannot be dissipative is kind of obvious for me now that you will always have this problem, not because of time nature, but because the math you chosen to model the phenomena (using only Lipschitz terms). And what makes thing worst, is that if I introduce a Non-Lipschitz term in any differential equation, but for analysing it I expand this nonlinearity using a truncated Taylor series (like what it is done in perturbation theory), I will destroy the system frequency response allowing only harmonics components (as I discuss here), and I will destroy also the possibility of having solutions of finite duration.

Possibly partially relevant? https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3700/4/9/011

Fluorescence is a quantum phenomenon, where excitations of electrons in discrete energy bands produce jumps that emit particular frequencies. I suspect a classical treatment would diverge fairly strongly from well-tested theory.

@AndersSandberg quantum is a math model (explanation), reality is it as it is, and fortunately is ridiculously consistent such math could be use to model it. I agree QM is the best explanation found so far, but I am wonder if it is also possible to use nonlinear diff. eqns. within the framework of EM wave eqns to model it. In this sense, QM also has limitations for describing this phenomena: think about How long it takes to an electron to do the jump among different energy levels? QM cannot give an accurate answer since is linear, it cannot show solutions with finite extinction times.

@Joako some more possibly partially related reading https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcc.25188

The fluorescence is due to chlorophyll, as is well known.

Harmonic generation is a well-known phenomenon in non-linear optics, but it necessarily involves the generation of higher frequencies of light rather than lower ones as observed here.

@MichaelSeifert I read that Wiki before, and is part of what I wonder about this questions... looks like the only possible alternatives are harmonics frequencies, but if I assume the new frequency generation happens in an interval of finite time extension, the phenomena should have a widespread spectrum due the Paley-Wiener theorem

I'd look at this from a rather different angle.  Since the incident, scattered and transmitted lights are all classical, one can just write down a purely classical model by fitting empirical data.  Or to start from a full quantum model, one can in principle integrate out all the quantumness and get an effective classical theory.  I mean, you can always write down a classical effective theory that works, but you have no idea why it works unless you see all the quantumness under the carpet.

@Vokaylop I would like to know How it could be done in classic ways? I mean, if it is possible to have a non-linear wave description that allow to show the frequency/color change on the emitted light

You ask whether there is classical effective theory, and there obviously must be.  I have no idea what or how.
